# date picker using java script which doesn't show future dates

Tags: javascript, php

I am running the following code for a date picker, and would like to know how to disable the selection of future dates, i.e. any date that occurs after the current date. Basically I need to remove the link from all future dates, so they appear but are not clickable. Any guidance is much appreciated... thanks!

```
// Converts a date into '12-Oct-1984' format
function getDateString(dt) {
  return dt.getDate() + '-' + 
        ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'][dt.getMonth()] + 
        '-' + dt.getFullYear();
}

//Modificado por mim function getDateString(dt) {   return dt.getDate() + '/' +      ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'][dt.getMonth()] +      '/' + dt.getFullYear(); } 

// Converts a date into 'July 2010' format
function getMonthYearString(dt) {
  return ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
        'August','September','October','November','December'][dt.getMonth()] +
        ' ' + dt.getFullYear();
}

// This is the function called when the user clicks any button
function chooseDate(e) {
  var targ; // Crossbrowser way to find the target (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        if (e.target) targ = e.target;
        else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
        if (targ.nodeType == 3) targ = targ.parentNode; // defeat Safari bug

  var div = targ.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode; // Find the div
  var idOfTextbox = div.getAttribute('datepickertextbox'); // Get the textbox id which was saved in the div
  var textbox = document.getElementById(idOfTextbox); // Find the textbox now
  if (targ.value=='<' || targ.value=='>') { // Do they want the change the month?
        createCalendar(div, new Date(targ.getAttribute('date')));
        return;
  }
  textbox.value = targ.getAttribute('date'); // Set the selected date
  div.parentNode.removeChild(div); // Remove the dropdown box now
}

// Parse a date in d-MMM-yyyy format
function parseMyDate(d) {
  if (d=="") return new Date('NotADate'); // For Safari
  var a = d.split('-');
  if (a.length!=3) return new Date(d); // Missing 2 dashes
  var m = -1; // Now find the month
  if (a[1]=='Jan') m=0;
  if (a[1]=='Feb') m=1;
  if (a[1]=='Mar') m=2;
  if (a[1]=='Apr') m=3;
  if (a[1]=='May') m=4;
  if (a[1]=='Jun') m=5;
  if (a[1]=='Jul') m=6;
  if (a[1]=='Aug') m=7;
  if (a[1]=='Sep') m=8;
  if (a[1]=='Oct') m=9;
  if (a[1]=='Nov') m=10;
  if (a[1]=='Dec') m=11;
  if (m<0) return new Date(d); // Couldn't find the month
  return new Date(a[2],m,a[0],0,0,0,0);
}

// This creates the calendar for a given month
function createCalendar(div, month) {
  var idOfTextbox = div.getAttribute('datepickertextbox'); // Get the textbox id which was saved in the div
  var textbox = document.getElementById(idOfTextbox); // Find the textbox now
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  var topRow = tbl.insertRow(-1);
  var td = topRow.insertCell(-1);
  var lastMonthBn = document.createElement('input');
  lastMonthBn.type='button'; // Have to immediately set the type due to IE
  td.appendChild(lastMonthBn);
  lastMonthBn.value='<';
  lastMonthBn.onclick=chooseDate;
  lastMonthBn.setAttribute('date',new Date(month.getFullYear(),month.getMonth()-1,1,0,0,0,0).toString());
  var td = topRow.insertCell(-1);
  td.colSpan=5;
  var mon = document.createElement('input');
  mon.type='text';
  td.appendChild(mon);
  mon.value = getMonthYearString(month);
  mon.size=15;
  mon.disabled='disabled';
  var td = topRow.insertCell(-1);
  var nextMonthBn = document.createElement('input');
  nextMonthBn.type='button';
  td.appendChild(nextMonthBn);
  nextMonthBn.value = '>';
  nextMonthBn.onclick=chooseDate;
  nextMonthBn.setAttribute('date',new Date(month.getFullYear(),month.getMonth()+1,1,0,0,0,0).toString());
  var daysRow = tbl.insertRow(-1);
  daysRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="Mon";
  daysRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="Tue";
  daysRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="Wed";
  daysRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="Thu";
  daysRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="Fri";
  daysRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="Sat";
  daysRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="Sun";

  // Make the calendar
  var selected = parseMyDate(textbox.value); // Try parsing the date
  var today = new Date();
  date = new Date(month.getFullYear(),month.getMonth(),1,0,0,0,0); // Starting at the 1st of the month
  var extras = (date.getDay() + 6) % 7; // How many days of the last month do we need to include?
  date.setDate(date.getDate()-extras); // Skip back to the previous monday
  while (1) { // Loop for each week
        var tr = tbl.insertRow(-1);
        for (i=0;i<7;i++) { // Loop each day of this week
        var td = tr.insertCell(-1);
        var inp = document.createElement('input');
        inp.type = 'button';
        td.appendChild(inp);
        inp.value = date.getDate();
        inp.onclick = chooseDate;
        inp.setAttribute('date',getDateString(date));
        if (date.getMonth() != month.getMonth()) {
        if (inp.className) inp.className += ' ';
        inp.className+='othermonth';
        }
        if (date.getDate()==today.getDate() && date.getMonth()==today.getMonth() && date.getFullYear()==today.getFullYear()) {
        if (inp.className) inp.className += ' ';
        inp.className+='today';
        }
        if (!isNaN(selected) && date.getDate()==selected.getDate() && date.getMonth()==selected.getMonth() && date.getFullYear()==selected.getFullYear()) {
        if (inp.className) inp.className += ' ';
        inp.className+='selected';
        }
        date.setDate(date.getDate()+1); // Increment a day
        }
        // We are done if we've moved on to the next month
        if (date.getMonth() != month.getMonth()) {
        break;
        }
  }

  // At the end, we do a quick insert of the newly made table, hopefully to remove any chance of screen flicker
  if (div.hasChildNodes()) { // For flicking between months
        div.replaceChild(tbl, div.childNodes[0]);
  } else { // For creating the calendar when they first click the icon
        div.appendChild(tbl);
  }
}

// This is called when they click the icon next to the date inputbox
function showDatePicker(idOfTextbox) {
  var textbox = document.getElementById(idOfTextbox);

  // See if the date picker is already there, if so, remove it
  x = textbox.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
        if (x[i].getAttribute('class')=='datepickerdropdown') {
        textbox.parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
        return false;
        }
  }

  // Grab the date, or use the current date if not valid
  var date = parseMyDate(textbox.value);
  if (isNaN(date)) date = new Date();

  // Create the box
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className='datepickerdropdown';
  div.setAttribute('datepickertextbox', idOfTextbox); // Remember the textbox id in the div
  createCalendar(div, date); // Create the calendar
  insertAfter(div, textbox); // Add the box to screen just after the textbox
  return false;
}

// Adds an item after an existing one
function insertAfter(newItem, existingItem) {
  if (existingItem.nextSibling) { // Find the next sibling, and add newItem before it
        existingItem.parentNode.insertBefore(newItem, existingItem.nextSibling); 
  } else { // In case the existingItem has no sibling after itself, append it
        existingItem.parentNode.appendChild(newItem);
  }
}

// This is called when the page loads, it searches for inputs where the class is 'datepicker'
function datePickerInit() {
  // Search for elements by class
  var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i=0; i<allElements.length; i++) {
        var className = allElements[i].className;
        if (className=='datepicker' || className.indexOf('datepicker ') != -1 || className.indexOf(' datepicker') != -1) {
        // Found one! Now lets add a datepicker next to it  
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href='#';
        a.className="datepickershow"
        a.setAttribute('onclick','return showDatePicker("' + allElements[i].id + '")');
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src='data:image/png;base64,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';
        img.title='Show calendar';
        a.appendChild(img);
        insertAfter(a, allElements[i]);
        }
  }
}

// Hook myself into the page load event
if (window.addEventListener) { // W3C standard
  window.addEventListener('load', datePickerInit, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) { // Microsoft
  window.attachEvent('onload', datePickerInit);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use jqueryui? http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois, no brother i must need to use javascript for this function. thats why :)

Comment: Uhm, jQuery UI is for javascript.

Comment: ha ha thats right bro,,,but i allowed to use this formatted date picker only.. :)